# Условие для выбранных checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

Нужно,чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, считывались выбранные чекбоксы и выполнялся запрос к базе данных учитывая выбранные условия, запросы напишу сам, но вот условия если выбраны сразу три выполняются все, а не одно которое только для 3-ёх.ID- трогать нельзя,по ним обрабатывается скрытие открытие дополнительных блоков!

```
      <form method="post">
          <h6>Какие критерии поиска учитывать при подборе?</h6>
           <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="on" id="checkbox1">Дата и Время<Br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="on" id="checkbox2">Цена<Br> 
           <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="on" id="checkbox3">Категория<Br> 
           </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="a1">
      </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['a1'])) {

        if ($_POST['option1']=="on" and $_POST['option2']=="on" and $_POST['option3']=="on") 
        { 
      print(33);
        } 
        if ($_POST['option1']=="on" and $_POST['option2']=="on") 
        { 
            print(12);
        } 
        if ($_POST['option1']=="on" and $_POST['option3']=="on") 
        { 
            print(13);
        } 
        if ($_POST['option2']=="on" and $_POST['option3']=="on") 
        { 
            print(23);
        } 
        if ($_POST['option1']=="on") 
        { 
            print(1);
        } 
        if ($_POST['option2']=="on" ) 
        { 
            print(2);
        } 
        if ($_POST['option3']=="on" ) 
        { 
            print(3);
        } 

    }
?>
```

Comment: `} else if (...) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
    flags = 0;
    if ($_POST['option1']=="on") 
    { 
        flags = flags + 1;
    } 
    if ($_POST['option2']=="on" ) 
    { 
        flags = flags + 2;
    } 
    if ($_POST['option3']=="on" ) 
    { 
        flags = flags + 4;
    } 

switch(flags) {
  case 1:
    option1 selected
  break;
  case 2:
    option2 selected
  break;
  case 3:
    option1, option2 selected
  break;
  case 4:
    option3 selected
  break;
  case 5:
    option1, option3 selected
  break;
  case 6:
    option2, option3 selected
  break;
  case 7:
    option1, option2, option3 selected
  break;
}
```

Comment: код разобрал, всё понятно и должно работать,на такой код ругается  в php поменял на $flags   и echo' option1, option2, option3 selected'; ,но ничего не происходит

Comment: @ВасилийСулим тут мне трудно будет Вам помочь, я имел в виду показать идею. Синтаксис php  я знаю плохо. Могу удалить ответ :).

Comment: да, нет всё верно, с головы совсем флаги со свичём вылетели, ответ дан по делу, просто немного изменить пришлось перменные, это не сложно), а вот почему оно не работает буду уже разбиратся, видимо где-то сам косанул

Comment: Всё заработало,как и думал ошибка была с моей стороны   имя дал option1[] , пытался использовать способ с массивом и забыл убрать)